# firebase storage reference with emoji not work

Tags: java, android, firebase, unicode, firebase-storage

current situation ist this: 
is have a firebase storeage link like this:

```
gs://mychattapp-3341d.appspot.com/chat/ibuymeadog%25F0%259F%2590%2595colorblack/videos/uploads/thumb_-LhPU00zSdgdcxa1VsJe.jpg
```

the part: %25F0%259F%2590%2595 is a emojie a dog.
[emojie dog](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f415/index.htm)

i have the same link like:

```
gs://mychattapp-3341d.appspot.com/chat/ibuymeadog%25F0%259F%2590%2595colorblack/videos/uploads/LhPU00zSdgdcxa1VsJe.mp4
```

the jpeg is my cover image for the video. i load the video with exoplayer this is no problem.

the coverimage i try to load with glide.
a link without emojie works fine.

now the problem:

a link with emojie dos not work, glide tell me:

```
2019-09-01 09:50:43.759 9254-10851/net.mychattapp E/StorageException: StorageException has occurred.
Object does not exist at location.
 Code: -13010 HttpResult: 404
```

what can i do to solve this problem?
please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your `Firebase` storage in your console then locate your image and click on it.

you will see `Storage location` and `Download URL` under the category *File Location* , copy the `Download URL` and use it in your `Glide` call.